# I want to get SUM of overtime column how i get

Tags: sql-server

```
 declare @system_name varchar;
WITH temp AS (
---get overtime of single date------
select Work_Date , max(DATEADD(ss,(datediff(ss,'6:45 PM',Work_EndTime )),CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))) as OverTime
from tblWorkTime where Work_Date between Work_StartTime and Work_EndTime and Work_EndTime > '6:45 PM'
AND system_name=@system_name group by Work_Date 
)

-----get sum of overtime of particuler 
Select cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff
(millisecond,0,cast(OverTime as datetime))),0) as time) as Overtime from temp
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your query the way you wrote it

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use SUM()?   Seems too obvious.

Comment: Tip:  Try adding an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) to this question.  It will improve the odds of getting an answer.

Comment: actually, the first query gives the result of two rows of overtime and  I want to add means sum and store it into on variable such as SumOfOverTime in above query OverTime Query is the tempory column.

Comment: Are you trying to sum time?  I.e half an hour + half an hour + half an hour =  `01:30:00.000`.  This time data type isn't designed for this.  It is designed to record times of the day (so in my example the answer is 1:30am not 1 hour 30 mins).  For this reason, you cannot sum time or dates.  Instead, convert to mins (or secs or hours) and sum that.  Would advise you don't convert back to time after.  So you final answer would be overtime = 90 mins (int datatype).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some assumptions about the schema and modified your sql a little. I have also returned the data in hours, minutes and seconds to avoid bigints. If you modify the code I am sure it will do what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #tblWorkTime ( system_name     VARCHAR(50)
                          , Work_Date       DATE
                          , Work_StartTime  TIME
                          , Work_EndTime    TIME )

INSERT INTO #tblWorkTime (system_name, Work_Date, Work_StartTime, Work_EndTime)  
  VALUES ( 'Foo', '20170101' , '09:00:00', '18:50:00.000')
       , ( 'Foo', '20170101' , '09:00:00', '19:50:00.000')

DECLARE @system_name VARCHAR(50) = 'Foo'

; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  Work_Date 
          , OverTimeHours       = DATEDIFF( SECOND,'18:45', Work_EndTime ) / 60 / 60
          , OverTimeMinutes     = DATEDIFF( SECOND,'18:45', Work_EndTime ) / 60 % 60
          , OverTimeSeconds     = DATEDIFF( SECOND,'18:45', Work_EndTime ) % 60 % 60         
    FROM    #tblWorkTime 
    WHERE   Work_EndTime >  '6:45 PM' 
      AND   system_name  =  @system_name 
)
SELECT  Work_Date
      , Hours   = SUM(OverTimeHours)
      , Minutes = SUM(OverTimeMinutes)
      , Seconds = SUM(OverTimeSeconds)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY Work_Date
```

Comment: Have I missed the mark or does this answer your question?

Comment: **Thank for this answer** it's working very well but I want one hours min sec in one column .... **how I merge that**

Comment: You could cast each as a varchar 2 , pad with a leading zero and concatenate with a colon. At this point you have the string representation that you could cast to time if you want.